how can i retrive birthdate from google people api?
public async Task<IActionResult> ExternalLoginCallback(string returnUrl, string remoteError)
{
    try
    {
        returnUrl = returnUrl ?? Url.Content("~/");
        LoginViewModel loginViewModel = new LoginViewModel
        {
            ReturnUrl = returnUrl,
            ExternalLogins = (await signInManager.GetExternalAuthenticationSchemesAsync()).ToList()
        };

        if (remoteError != null)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, $"Error from external provider: {remoteError}");
            return View("Login", loginViewModel);
        }

        var info = await signInManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
        if (info == null)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Error loading external login information.");
            return View("Login", loginViewModel);
        }

        var signInResult = await signInManager.ExternalLoginSignInAsync(info.LoginProvider, info.ProviderKey, isPersistent: false, bypassTwoFactor: true);
            if (signInResult.Succeeded)
        {
            var user = await userManager.FindByEmailAsync(info.Principal.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Email));
            //var birthdate = info.Principal.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.DateOfBirth);
            var birthdateClaim = info.Principal.FindFirst("urn:google:birthday");
            var accessToken = info.AuthenticationTokens.FirstOrDefault(token => token.Name == "access_token")?.Value;
            var refreshToken = info.AuthenticationTokens.FirstOrDefault(token => token.Name == "refresh_token")?.Value;
            if (birthdateClaim != null)
            {
                var birthdate = DateTime.Parse(birthdateClaim.Value);
            }            
        }
     }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        logger.LogError(ex, "An error occurred during external login callback.");
        return RedirectToAction("Error", "Home");
    }
}

This is my controller code:
builder.Services.AddAuthentication().AddGoogle(googleOptions =>
{
    googleOptions.ClientId = "<clientId>";
    googleOptions.ClientSecret = "<clientSecret>";

    //googleOptions.Scope.Add("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile");
    //googleOptions.Scope.Add("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email");
    googleOptions.Scope.Add("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/user.birthday.read");


    //googleOptions.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey("urn:google:picture", "picture", "url");
    //googleOptions.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey("urn:google:locale", "locale", "string");
    //googleOptions.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey("urn:google:birthday", "birthday", "date");

    googleOptions.SaveTokens = true;

    googleOptions.Events.OnCreatingTicket = ctx =>
    {
        List<AuthenticationToken> tokens = ctx.Properties.GetTokens().ToList();

        tokens.Add(new AuthenticationToken()
        {
            Name = "TicketCreated",
            Value = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString()
        });

        ctx.Properties.StoreTokens(tokens);

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    };
});

This code is in my program.cs - I'm getting profile-picture and email by using this but i cant get birthdate or gender how can i get it ?
there is no error showing just showing null in birthdate i don;t know why and please if you guys have any document reference for the same then provide me

check here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72874742/how-could-i-obtain-the-users-gender-and-birthday-after-they-sign-in-with-their. I think you need to do an additional request to get the data https://stackoverflow.com/a/67531234/106866
